# Strange chrome or jquery behaviour on adding a class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

When I open `elements tab` in Chrome (Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit))

I see - 
`<img id="marked" src="marked.png" class="ltmargin">`

However, when I write `$("#marked")[0]` in `console tab`
I see - 
 
`<img id="marked" src="marked.png" class="ltmargin hidenow">`

Also, `$("#marked").length` is `1`

`hidenow` class is supposed to hide the image (`display: none`) and is working fine for elements on which `hidenow` is added inside the html file. The image on the page is visible. 
 
In my js file, I add `hidenow` to `#marked` using jquery `.addClass()` but it doesn't show up in html!

Has anyone encountered this before? How should I debug this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that id of `#marked` was actually `#moremark` before and was being changed in js, adding a class after it did not work. So I did this -

```
$("#moremarked").addClass("hidenow");
// change id after adding the class
$("#moremarked").prop("id", "marked");
```

and everything is working fine!